# Get all scope variables used on an element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have a template like this:

```
<awesome>{{scopeVariable1}} - {{scopeVariable2 | filteryThing}}</awesome>
```

In my `awesome` directive, I need to know that `scopeVariable1` and `scopeVariable2` exist on the template, so that I add watches to them and know when to rerun a css transform on `awesome`.

Is there a way to capture those two variables in some angular-ey way so I don't have to run a regex to search for them? I just need to watch all scope variables in my `awesome` element.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want to do here, and a live plunkr could be helpful, but if you want to track the scope variables from within a directive, you can always copy the scope and use $watch (or $watchCollection).

Comment: So you're saying i should just copy the scope and do $watch(scope) instead of creating keys to watch?

Comment: are you trying to capture the values from the variables?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to know when the values update so i know to re-run some CSS stuff based on the final values.

Comment: So yea - all you need to do in your directive is:
`$scope.$watch('scopeVariable1',function(newVal, oldVal, $scope){
//do something on change
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `awesome` directive's `compile` step, I ended up doing this:

```
watchableKeys = _.uniq $(tElement).text()
  # find all angular mustache-style tags
  .match(///{{ #grab the first {{
    \s* # whitespace
    [\w\.\s* \|]+ # capture words, whitespaces, pipes
    \s* # trailing whitespace
    }} # mustaches
    ///g)
  #... only get the first word, since that's the scope value to watch for.
  .map((x)-> x.match(/[\w\.]+/)[0])
```

Then in the `post link` function, I iterate over `watchableKeys` and `$watch` each one.

```
for key in watchableKeys
  scope.$watch key, (newValue) ->
    # do things
```

Answer (score 0):

I created [this example](http://codepen.io/arg20/pen/oECnI). I hope this is what you're looking for.

```
appModule.directive('awesome', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        val1: "=",
        val2: "="
      },
      template: "<div>{{val1}} - {{val2}}</div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 

        var triggerUpdate  = function(oldVal, newVal){  
            if (oldVal !== newVal) {
                //place your update here
                alert("changed!");
            }
        }
        scope.$watch('val1',triggerUpdate);
        scope.$watch('val2',triggerUpdate);
  }
};
```

});

I use an isolate scope so you can reuse the directive many times in the same view with one controller. If you wish not to do so, simply watch the scope properties you're interested in, it's hard to know which one is best without knowing the context in which you will use this directive.